# (ContentType/DisplayType)-specific alternate to Layout shape in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I use `Orchard 1.10.1`.

Is it possible to create a (`ContentType`/`DisplayType`)-specific alternate to Layout shape in Orchard?

I need a specific alternate to Layout for  `CustomContentType` in `Displaytype` Detail.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like the Layout shape has alternates set up out of the box:

- https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/dev/src/Orchard.Web/Core/Shapes/CoreShapes.cs#L52

If you scroll down a bit to the next one, `Zone` then you will see that it has an `OnDisplaying()` event handler which adds Alternates at the end.

I'm not sure if there is a built in trick that supports this that I don't know about. Assuming there isn't any special casing of "Layout" that I also don't know about, you could make your own `IShapeTableProvider` which adds in some alternates to match your requirements.

There appears to be [a tutorial over on Bertrands blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/switching-the-layout-in-orchard-cms) which explains some ideas how you can do this.

In the comments it also mentions that you can enable the Url Alternates feature of the Shape Tracer which might help you sort this.

Comment: Thanks, great guide.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an exemple for a ContentType based Layout alternante provider :

```
public class LayoutAlternateProvider : ContentHandler
{
    string contentType;
    private readonly IWorkContextAccessor _workContextAccessor;

    protected override void BuildDisplayShape(BuildDisplayContext context)
    {
        if (context.DisplayType == "Detail" && !IsWidget(context.ContentItem))
        {
            context.Layout.Metadata.Alternates.Add("Layout__" + context.ContentItem.ContentType);
        }
    }

    private static bool IsWidget(ContentItem item)
    {
        return item.TypeDefinition.Settings.Any(setting => setting.Key == "Stereotype" && setting.Value == "Widget");
    }
}
```